# Wordpress loads menu images over HTTP instead of HTTPS. Can you define the base URL to use HTTPS?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, https

I'm wondering if it's possible to override the base URL used by the Appearance > Menus feature in WordPress.

No additional plugins being used here, this is standard WordPress functionality.

By default it defines the base path as the wp-content/uploads/ path, but it uses the HTTP base url, even when the request is HTTPS. This means I'm getting insecure content warnings in the browser.

I've tried using plugins to force HTTPS but this is slipping the net. Can't find anywhere in the Wordpress config UI to set the content directory manually. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 2 url variables under the Settings (/wp-admin/options-general.php)

- WordPress Address (URL)
- Site Address (URL)

They control all the content. Try to switch it https:// ? If not you can force the https using an .htaccess trick:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

My advice is to check this article as well:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL

Comment: Thanks - it's hosted on a machine with no system access i.e. we can't dial in over SSH. I'd have thrown in a load of redirect rules otherwise! I've tried every plugin I can find to force HTTPS and none of them are working.

Comment: Both of those options are set to use https as well.